# How to auto run Android application after build in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Last night, I clicked "run" button and Android Studio built my app.
But after completing the build task, it did not work on my device anymore.

How to fix that? Do I have to set the auto run option?

I checked the application installation on my device.
My issue is that "autorun on device" does not work.

Comment: I inform you one more thing. I checked application installation in my device. My issue is just one thing. It is not work "autorun on device". thanks~

Comment: Ha~ Thank you Rotwang~ I will be more careful  >ㅡ<

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open the Gradle tab that is on the right side of the Android Studio UI.

Find the `installDebug` option, and the Run button will use that as the "last ran" command.

[image: Android Studio Gradle]

If you are otherwise unable to run the app, then you may have a compilation issue

Comment: thank you so much^^~ I was founded a solution. File > Setting > Build, Execution.. > Instant run > Enable Instant Run ... is unchecked! I really appreciate your comment!

Comment: Instant Run is different than the true "run button", but glad to hear